# undefined id while getting id from div tag

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I'm trying to get recordId from HTML and its not getting.

```
 <template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">
                  <p key={contact.id}>{contact.name}</p>
              </template>
              
              
              <template iterator:it={contacts.data}>
                
                        <div class="my-card"  key={it.value.id}  onclick={navigateToNewContactPage} data-id={contact.id} >

                                 <h3>{it.value.Name}</h3> <br>

                                  Title: {it.value.Title}<br>

                                  Phone: {it.value.Phone} <br>

                                  Email: {it.value.Email} <br><br>
                        </div>
                
              </template>
          </template>
```

JS:

```
let Ids;


export default class GetContactOnAccount extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track searchKey = '';
    @api recordId;
    

    @wire(findContacts, { searchKey: '$searchKey' })
    contacts;

    connectedCallback(){
        this.searchKey = this.recordId;
    }

    navigateToNewContactPage(event) {
        const recordId  = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        console.log('recordId', recordId);
        console.log('event', event);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId,
                objectApiName: 'Contact',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
        });
```

Comment: I can't see `idFetched` being called anywhere. Please use [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/370582/edit) & add relevant information.

Comment: I used that function only to store id into a variable. now i removed it. @SachinHooda

Comment: why are you using an iterator within a for:Each directive? this is a bad design, why not use one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a global variable to hold the ids of the elements that were clicked. Because you can directly get the details of the element that bubbled this click event. Your function `navigateToNewContactPage` should be like,

```
navigateToNewContactPage(event) {
            const recordId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId,
                    objectApiName: 'Contact',
                    actionName: 'view'
                },
            });
```

Also elements declared outside the class can be used without referencing them with `this`.

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: the error looks like this " [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')]"

Comment: Can you pls add updated code to the question?

Comment: okay, updated...

Comment: And this log `console.log('recordId', recordId);` never appears in console??

Comment: No. Actually its my browser cache problem. I cleared all cache and tried. it was working now. Anyway thanks for you help

Comment: Great! you can mark your question as solved. Feel free to [ask another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you've any other issues.